# How to turn off Outlook Notifications?

Tags: notifications, microsoft-outlook-2003

I like email to stay an asynchronous system as it was designed. Whenever I receive an outlook email notification, I get out of my work flow and become unproductive, "event-driven"...

How do I turn the notification in Outlook off? I'm using 2003...

P.S: I would opt for not using outlook at all but unfortunately at the company I work at, I have to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only got access to Outlook 2007 but I believe the options are the same:

**Tools > Options > E-mail Options > Advanced E-mail Options...**

In this dialog there's a section headed "When new items arrive in my Inbox".

[image]

Clear them all.

*I've no idea why these options are buried so deep within the UI - it's bad design.*

Answer (score 2):

1. From the Tools menu select Options.
2. Click the Preferences tab.
3. Click the Email Options button.
4. Uncheck "Display a notification message when new mail arrives."

Answer (score 1):

Under **Tools -> Options -> Preferences -> Email Options -> Advanced Email Options** you can configure how you are alerted and optionally turn them off.